# Centring CSS Grid Layout cards

Tags: html, css, css-grid

After i made with some help some CSS Grid Layouts where they are as well web responsive and Mobile i have a issue to center these card.
I tried justify-content:center on the Grid container without much success!
Any clue?

I have a image as well attached
[image]
Below the css and html code

```
   .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-area:test;
    background-color: blue;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    
    grid-gap: 20px;
 
    align-items: stretch;
 
  }

  article{
    padding:10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    
    
    
  }

  .grid>article {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    display: flex; /* <-------------- changes */
    flex-direction: column; /* <-------------- changes */
    
  }
  
  .grid>article img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  
  .text {
    padding: 0 20px 20px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex; /* <-------------- changes */
    flex-direction: column; /* <-------------- changes */
  }
  
  .text>p {
    flex-grow: 1; /* <-------------- changes */
  }
  
  .text>button {
    background: gray;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

HTML

```
 <main class="grid">
        <article>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="Sample photo">
          <div class="text">
            <h3>Seamlessly visualize quality</h3>
            <p>Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks.</p>
            <button>Here's why</button>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="Sample photo">
          <div class="text">
            <h3>Completely Synergize</h3>
            <p>Dramatically engage seamlessly visualize quality intellectual capital without superior collaboration and idea-sharing.</p>
            <button>Here's how</button>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="Sample photo">
          <div class="text">
            <h3>Dynamically Procrastinate</h3>
            <p>Completely synergize resource taxing relationships via premier niche markets.</p>
            <button>Read more</button>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="Sample photo">
          <div class="text">
            <h3>Best in class</h3>
            <p>Imagine jumping into that boat, and just letting it sail wherever the wind takes you...</p>
            <button>Just do it...</button>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article>
```

also anyone would have a better suggestion design for dynamic web responsive CSS Grid Layout cards? Though i like their current width and height when the browser reach a specific viewport they are getting squarish.

Edit: When i am using repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px,1fr)); instead of the parameter auto-fill i am getting this ugly streching.On my full browsers viewport though. When i minimize the window they get as they were with auto-fill in the first pict

[image: auto-fit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is arising with your usage of auto-fill. Based on [this resource](https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/#fill-or-fit-whats-the-difference) from the excellent blog css-tricks, auto-fill will create empty columns to fill the screen (with a min width of 200px, as you've specified).

> auto-fill FILLS the row with as many columns as it can fit. So it creates implicit columns whenever a new column can fit, because it’s trying to FILL the row with as many columns as it can. The newly added columns can and may be empty, but they will still occupy a designated space in the row.

> auto-fit FITS the CURRENTLY AVAILABLE columns into the space by expanding them so that they take up any available space. The browser does that after FILLING that extra space with extra columns (as with auto-fill ) and then collapsing the empty ones.

Try changing to

```
.grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  }
```

Comment: thank you! I did but the issue remains since it is practically stretching the four cards to fill the entire widht of the grid container making it look kinda ugly as too pixelized stretched boxes.

Comment: according to that excellent resource "If you’re using auto-fit, the content will stretch to fill the entire row width." so thats why with auto-fit they are getting kinda ugly. I edited my thread so you can see what i mean

Comment: You could increase the minmax of the grid frs (or the gutter). If you want to keep the size of the cards the same, you could wrap them in a container element and give that padding. But for your use case flexbox with justify-content: space-between (or space evenly), might work better. It'll definitely be easier too.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the first suggestion so i wrapped the grid container with another Grid container and i gave the paddings that i wanted and it works like a charm. Specifically,  .testContainer {
    display: grid;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right:30px;
  }
Though its kinda strange that it works only when this testContainer is grid. When display property is set to inline-block or flex it doesnt work exactly like that.

Comment: Great! Did that resolve all your issues? If so, could you please mark the answer as correct. Otherwise, can I help with anything else?

Comment: Yes sorry i just woke up and i am still laggy!! Thank you so much for your helpful suggestions! I would like only your opinion if for mobile devices if i should set media queries for the cards and use any other more proper settings!

Comment: Auto-fit I believe should cascade onto a new line for mobile devices, but there's no substitute for playing around with device widths and seeing what adjustments need to be made. This article (https://thoughtbot.com/blog/concise-media-queries-with-css-grid) might be valuable. Also, I would learn about common breakpoints (https://medium.com/@uiuxlab/the-most-used-responsive-breakpoints-in-2017-of-mine-9588e9bd3a8a) and target specifically those so there is some organization to your media queries.

Comment: thank you sir! your information and guides are a treasure! Since cards are practical the fundamental of my webpage since i ll set up a city guide review city!